# Mockito returning results from database and not results from when()

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, mockito

I have this problem where Mockito returns the result the actual controller would have given if the service has started. I want it to return the goats list I made and set in the when() function.

```
package com.goatpool.goatpool;

import com.goatpool.goatpool.controller.GoatController;
import com.goatpool.goatpool.model.Goat;
import com.goatpool.goatpool.service.HBMGoatService;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class GoatControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    GoatController goatController;

    @Mock
    HBMGoatService hbmgoatService;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        //runs before the tests
    }

    @Test
    void testGetAllGoats() throws Exception {
        //Arrange
        List<Goat> goats = new ArrayList<>();
        goats.add(new Goat(1, "1","20001","buck", new Date() ,12.02f,1,3,24.68f,null,"Some Info",true,100));
        goats.add(new Goat(2,"2","20056","doe",new Date() ,16.02f,1,3,20.68f,null ,"Some Info",true,12));
        goats.add(new Goat(3,"3","21060","doe",new Date() ,16.02f,1,3,0f,null,"No Info",true,12));
        goats.add(new Goat(4,"4","1212","buck",new Date() ,1.3f,1,3,0.5f,null,"No Info",true,12));

        //Act
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Mockito.when(hbmgoatService.getGoatList()).thenReturn(goats); //mock
        List<Goat> result = goatController.getAllGoats();

        //Assert
        String actualResults = result.toString();
        String expectedResults = goats.toString();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResults, actualResults);
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely, `@InjectMocks` doesnt correctly inject. There are plenty of reason why that step might go wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584454/injecting-mocks-with-mockito-does-not-work for example.

Comment: I think, you are using junit jupiter API, then you should use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class` instead, also you don't need explicit call to `MockitoAnnotations#init`.