# @Transactional annotation overwrites Mockito's InjectMocks

Tags: java, transactions, mockito, junit5

In class TeacherDao method create() calls AddressDao.create():

```java
public void create(Teacher teacher) {
    addressDao.create(teacher.getAddress());
    // Teacher is being written to database...
}
```

I am writing a Junit5 test for TeacherDao class, so AddressDao is replaced with a mock.
I call TeacherDao.create() and verify that AddressDao.create() is being interacted:

```java
@Mock
private AddressDao addressDao;
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private TeacherDao teacherDao;
@Test
void teacherDaoCreateTest() {
     teacherDao.create(teacher);
     verify(addressDao).create(testAddress);
}
```

Verification is successful.
After that I add @Transactional annotation to TeacherDao.create() method, and test fails.
AddressDao mock now has zero interactions, and testAddress is being actually written to the database.
I don't totally understand how @Transactional works in-depth and must be missing something important. Why @Transactional rewrites mocks?

Comment: Which mockito version do you use ?

Comment: Mockito ver.3.8.0.

Comment: Did you take a look at the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124326/how-to-inject-mock-into-service-that-has-transactional

Comment: I did, that question was asked 8 years ago, Mockito and Spring could go far away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the @Autowired annotation.